# UDP: What is the right transport hint?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the various tutorials and ROS documentation I have seen the following variants of hinting that
UDP packets should be used. Which is optimal for receiving the current AtlasStates message in DRCSIM?

```
jointStatesSo.transport_hints = ros::TransportHints().unreliable();
atlasStateSo.transport_hints = ros::TransportHints().reliable().tcpNoDelay(true)
jointStatesSo.transport_hints = ros::TransportHints().unreliable().reliable().tcpNoDelay(true);
```

On a side note, I am assuming the hand commands and states will switch to UDP as well?

What about IMU packets?

atlas_msgs/AtlasSimInterfaceState? atlas_msgs/AtlasSimInterfaceCommand?

controller_statistics?

clock messages?

Image transport?
stereo proc messages?

laser spindle joint states?

laser scans?

Thanks,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2592/udp:-what-is-the-right-transport-hint?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-04-28**:
[https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/226/atlas\_sim\_interface\_state-needs-timestamp](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/226/atlas%5C_sim%5C_interface%5C_state-needs-timestamp) for similar discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0